# Collecting data from an array and filter with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

First of all thanks for the coments to make the post understable.
I'm from argentina and evidently my english is not good enough.

I'm being trained as a junior developer and my task is to filter by party a json array within senators of the goverment with three checkboxes.
At the moment I have my HTML code with the checkboxes, they have onchange property, then in my javascript code I used

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=party]:checked')).map(elt => elt.value)`

to take the array with the value of the checkboxes, but I have no idea how to compare the checkbox value with the json array to filter what I need.

Here we've got the code at the moment

HTML:

`<div class='row'>
                <b>Filter by Party:</b>
                <label for='Republican'>Republican</label>
                <input onchange="partyFilter" type='checkbox' name='party' id='Republican' value='R'>
                <label for='Democrat'>Democrat</label>
                <input onchange="partyFilter" type='checkbox' name='party' id='Democrat' value='D'>
                <label for='Independent'>Independent</label>
                <input onchange="partyFilter" type='checkbox' name='party' id='Independent' value='I'>
            </div>`

JAVASCRIPT (taking checkboxes values)

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=party]:checked')).map(elt => elt.value)`

JAVASCRIPT (filtering my array to take the "party" value

`miembros.filter(rep => rep.party === 'R')
miembros.filter(dem => rep.party === 'D')
miembros.filter(ind => rep.party === 'I')`

I thought that you wont need the json code, but i got it wrong.
Here is an example of the json code with the array inside it.

JSON ARRAY:

`
var data = 
{
   "status":"OK",
   "copyright":" Copyright (c) 2019 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
   "results":[
      {
         "congress": "116",
         "chamber": "Senate",

```
     "num_results": 100,
     "offset": 0,
     "members": [
          {
             "id": "A000360",
             "title": "Senator, 2nd Class",
             "short_title": "Sen.",
             "api_uri":"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/A000360.json",
             "first_name": "Lamar",
             "middle_name": null,
             "last_name": "Alexander",
             "suffix": null,
             "date_of_birth": "1940-07-03",
             "gender": "M",
             "party": "R",
             "leadership_role": null,
             "twitter_account": "SenAlexander",
             "facebook_account": "senatorlamaralexander",
             "youtube_account": "lamaralexander",
             "govtrack_id": "300002",
             "cspan_id": "5",
             "votesmart_id": "15691",
             "icpsr_id": "40304",
             "crp_id": "N00009888",
             "google_entity_id": "/m/01rbs3",
             "fec_candidate_id": "S2TN00058",
             "url": "https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public",
             "rss_url": "https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/?a=RSS.Feed",
             "contact_form": "http://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=Email",
             "in_office": true,
             "cook_pvi": null,
             "dw_nominate": 0.324,
             "ideal_point": null,
             "seniority": "17",
             "next_election": "2020",
             "total_votes": 386,
             "missed_votes": 76,
             "total_present": 0,
             "last_updated": "2019-12-10 06:56:21 -0500",
             "ocd_id": "ocd-division/country:us/state:tn",
             "office": "455 Dirksen Senate Office Building",
             "phone": "202-224-4944",
             "fax": "202-228-3398",
             "state": "TN",
             "senate_class": "2",
             "state_rank": "senior",
             "lis_id": "S289"
             ,"missed_votes_pct": 19.69,
             "votes_with_party_pct": 97.09,
             "votes_against_party_pct": 2.91
           },
                       {
             "id": "B001230",
             "title": "Senator, 1st Class",
             "short_title": "Sen.",
             "api_uri":"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/B001230.json",
             "first_name": "Tammy",
             "middle_name": null,
             "last_name": "Baldwin",
             "suffix": null,
             "date_of_birth": "1962-02-11",
             "gender": "F",
             "party": "D",
             "leadership_role": null,
             "twitter_account": "SenatorBaldwin",
             "facebook_account": "senatortammybaldwin",
             "youtube_account": "witammybaldwin",
             "govtrack_id": "400013",
             "cspan_id": "57884",
             "votesmart_id": "3470",
             "icpsr_id": "29940",
             "crp_id": "N00004367",
             "google_entity_id": "/m/024v02",
             "fec_candidate_id": "H8WI00018",
             "url": "https://www.baldwin.senate.gov",
             "rss_url": "https://www.baldwin.senate.gov/rss/feeds/?type=all",
             "contact_form": "https://www.baldwin.senate.gov/feedback",
             "in_office": true,
             "cook_pvi": null,
             "dw_nominate": -0.502,
             "ideal_point": null,
             "seniority": "7",
             "next_election": "2024",
             "total_votes": 386,
             "missed_votes": 1,
             "total_present": 1,
             "last_updated": "2019-12-10 06:56:22 -0500",
             "ocd_id": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wi",
             "office": "709 Hart Senate Office Building",
             "phone": "202-224-5653",
             "fax": null,
             "state": "WI",
             "senate_class": "1",
             "state_rank": "junior",
             "lis_id": "S354"
             ,"missed_votes_pct": 0.26,
             "votes_with_party_pct": 93.83,
             "votes_against_party_pct": 6.17
           },
                       {
             "id": "B001261",
             "title": "Senator, 1st Class",
             "short_title": "Sen.",
             "api_uri":"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/B001261.json",
             "first_name": "John",
             "middle_name": null,
             "last_name": "Barrasso",
             "suffix": null,
             "date_of_birth": "1952-07-21",
             "gender": "M",
             "party": "R",
             "leadership_role": "Senate Republican Conference Chair",
             "twitter_account": "SenJohnBarrasso",
             "facebook_account": "johnbarrasso",
             "youtube_account": "barrassowyo",
             "govtrack_id": "412251",
             "cspan_id": "1024777",
             "votesmart_id": "52662",
             "icpsr_id": "40707",
             "crp_id": "N00006236",
             "google_entity_id": "/m/02rsm32",
             "fec_candidate_id": "S6WY00068",
             "url": "https://www.barrasso.senate.gov",
             "rss_url": "https://www.barrasso.senate.gov/public/?a=rss.feed",
             "contact_form": "https://www.barrasso.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/contact-form",
             "in_office": true,
             "cook_pvi": null,
             "dw_nominate": 0.538,
             "ideal_point": null,
             "seniority": "13",
             "next_election": "2024",
             "total_votes": 386,
             "missed_votes": 0,
             "total_present": 0,
             "last_updated": "2019-12-09 19:32:09 -0500",
             "ocd_id": "ocd-division/country:us/state:wy",
             "office": "307 Dirksen Senate Office Building",
             "phone": "202-224-6441",
             "fax": null,
             "state": "WY",
             "senate_class": "1",
             "state_rank": "junior",
             "lis_id": "S317"
             ,"missed_votes_pct": 0.00,
             "votes_with_party_pct": 96.88,
             "votes_against_party_pct": 3.13
           },`
```

I've no idea how to connect the values received with mi javascript function to filter the array.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What are you trying to filter and what is the thing to filter against? If possible, create a Stackblitz or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array of checked values within your filter like so:

```js
const checked = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=party]:checked')).map(elt => elt.value)
miembros.filter(rep => checked.includes(rep.party))
```

This will return an array containing only the objects from the `miembros` array which have a `party` attribute that matches one of the checked values.

Comment: I also think that this is what he wants. The `const checked` contains the values of the checkboxes. His data array (called miembros?) has be to be filtered against it, which means the include. Do note that you have to return `miembros.filter(...)` as filter creates a new array

Comment: That's right. The code that James gave to me is ok, but i need to make it interactive, filtering the json array at the moment with the checkbox value, the result should be displayed in the table that i created with html (done)